# jQuery: Is CheckBox checked on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#CustomersResellers').hide();

    $('input.ShowResellerAccounts').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert('checked');
        }
    });
});
```

which shows the alert when I check the box, but if the box is already checked on page load, it does not show the alert.

Comment: It's not going to magically make an event for you

Comment: Usually you would append a similar event trigger at the end of event listener code: `$('selector').on('event', handler).trigger('event')`; in this case you can use `.trigger('click')` or just `.click()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it should not be shown, because nowhere in your code you attached event handler when checkbox is checked. So just add a hanlder, when checkbox is checked, like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#CustomersResellers').hide();

    // Define a handle to avoid duplication 
    function handler(){
      alert('checked');   
    }

    if ($('input.ShowResellerAccounts').is(':checked')){
       handler();
    }

    $('input.ShowResellerAccounts').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            handler();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets update the function:

```
var alertChecked = function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    alert('checked');
  }
}

// invoke the function when clicked
$('input.ShowResellerAccounts').on('click', alertChecked); 

//invoke the function for all matching elements
$('input.ShowResellerAccounts').each(alertChecked);
```

Comment: I would also use this approach given the problem OP is facing. Instead of rewriting the function twice, this compresses the code :) and makes it verbose, too. +1.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the behavior I would expect. 
`if $(this).is(':checked')` means 'if this checkbox is checked' - then show the alert. But when you click to uncheck the box (`on('click'...)`), it becomes unchecked and alert does not show.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a **very slight change** and you're there:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#CustomersResellers').hide();

    $('input.ShowResellerAccounts').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            alert('checked');
        }
    })
    .trigger('click'); //<<<===== This is all you need to add :)
});
```

Usually you would append a similar event trigger at the end of event listener code:

```
$('selector').on('event', handler).trigger('event');
```

In your case you can use `.trigger('click')` or just `.click()`. Very clean and straight forward :)

**SPECIAL NOTE**

And since you're dealing with a checkbox (and not a button) I would favor the `change` event over the `click` event.